If condition inside the useEffect isn't working
const [formData, setFormdata] = useState({});
path = "abc"  // path is a string passed as prop
useEffect(() => {
  // console.log('Table component rendered');
  
  if (formData[path] === undefined) {
    serviceProvider(
      ctx,
      uischemaData,
      {
        event: { _reactName: "onLoad" },
        path,
        ...uischemaData.additionalData,
      }
    ).then((res: any) => {
      const fetchedData = res[path]?.map((e) => {
        return e;
      });
      setFormdata((pre) => {
        return {
          ...pre,
          [path]: fetchedData,
        };
      });
      setTableData(fetchedData || []);
    });
  }

I want to call the function name serviceProvider when formData[path] === undefined and when the component mounts, but the problem is when the formData[path] equals to undefined(checked on debugger) then it does not go inside the if condition.How's that even possible?
Basically this useEffect calls an API through the serviceProvider function on component(Table) mount and res is stored in the formData, so another time the same table is rendered then it does not need to call the API again.

Remember that your useEffect() will run twice in StrictMode.

your useEffect provided in the question is missing its dependency array as second parameter.
useEffect(() => {
...
}, [...]);

The below code snippet works, please check:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormdata] = useState({});
  let path = 'abc';

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formData[path] === undefined) {
      console.log('path does not exist');
      setFormdata((pre) => {
        return {
          ...pre,
          [path]: 'hello',
        };
      });
    } else console.log('path exist');
  }, []);

  console.log(formData);

  return <div></div>;
}

The above code snippet is pretty straightforward implementation of the code provided in the question.
Please check your implementation of the function serviceProvider.

Please explain what you have changed and why that solves the problem.

 import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
 const Table = ({ path }) => {
 const [formData, setFormdata] = useState({});
 const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
if (formData[path] === undefined) {
  serviceProvider(
    ctx,
    uischemaData,
    {
      event: { _reactName: "onLoad" },
      path,
      ...uischemaData.additionalData,
    }
  ).then((res) => {
    const fetchedData = res[path]?.map((e) => e);
    setFormdata((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [path]: fetchedData,
    }));
    setTableData(fetchedData || []);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  });
}
}, [path, formData]);
return (
 <div>
   {
   tableData.map((item, index) => (
     <div key={index}>{item}</div>
   ))}
 </div>
);
};
export default Table;


Please explain what you have changed and why that solves the problem.

The issue you're facing where formData[path] is undefined but the code does not enter the if condition might be due to the following reasons:
Initial state of formData: Ensure that formData is initialized correctly. It should be an object, and path should be a string.
Component lifecycle: The component might be re-rendering in a way that causes the useEffect to be called again but not updating formData[path] as expected.

I am not the original asker, I was asking that you edit your answer to clarify what your proposed solution is.
